# Type error for gdal- GDAL-style transforms have been deprecated

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff, rasterio, numpy, transform

I'm trying to export numpy ndarray that I have to TIFF using rasterio.
I have the transform of the image:

```
print(transf)
>>>(583932.1992386435, 10.0, 0, 2223772.1491772938, 0, -10.0)
```

When I use this when I save the raster I recieve error :

```
    with rasterio.open('test.tiff', 
                       'w',
                       driver='GTiff',
                       height=img.shape[0],
                       width=img.shape[1],
                       count=3,
                       dtype=img.dtype,
                       crs=rasterio.crs.CRS.from_dict(init='epsg:4326'),
                       nodata=None, # change if data has nodata value
                       transform=transf) as dst:
        dst.write(vi[:,:,0], 1)
        dst.write(vi[:,:,1], 2)
        dst.write(vi[:,:,2], 3)
```

> TypeError: GDAL-style transforms have been deprecated.  This exception
> will be raised for a period of time to highlight potentially confusing
> errors, but will eventually be removed.

I haven't found any posts in regard to this error. How can I change it? How can I save my result ndarray int TIFF given the transform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Affine.from_gdal` method to convert any existing GDAL-style transforms:

```
from affine import Affine

transf = (583932.1992386435, 10.0, 0, 2223772.1491772938, 0, -10.0)
afn = Affine.from_gdal(*transf)
```

Now pass `afn` to rasterio's `transform` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Explanation of the why at https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/blob/master/docs/topics/migrating-to-v1.rst#migrating-to-rasterio-10

Explanation of how to fix your code with this issue comment https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/1830#issuecomment-601446758. First link is useful for order of args between old style e.g GDAL geotransform  and new style e.g affine.Affine

In your case,

```py
#(c, a, b, f, d, e)
transf = (583932.1992386435, 10.0, 0, 2223772.1491772938, 0, -10.0)
```

should become

```py
from rasterio import Affine as A

#affine.Affine(a, b, c,
#              d, e, f)

transf = A(10.0, 0.0, 583932.1992386435,
            0.0, -10.0, 2223772.1491772938,)
```

In the `rasterio.open`, continue to use `transform=transf` as it accepts an Affine object.